# Boost::Asio UDP connection order

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, udp, boost-asio

I have an UDPServer that transmits to the UDPClient via:

```
UDPServer::UDPServer() :
  port_number_(1122),
  socket_(io_, ba::ip::udp::v4()),
  endpoint_client_(ba::ip::address::from_string("127.0.0.1"), port_number_)
{
  socket_.set_option(boost::asio::socket_base::reuse_address(true));
  socket_.bind(ba::ip::udp::endpoint(ba::ip::udp::v4(), port_number_));
}

void UDPServer::SendState(const std::vector<float>& state) {
  socket_.send_to(ba::buffer(state), endpoint_client_);
}
```

And UDPClient receives data via:

```
UDPClient::UDPClient():
  port_number_(1122),
  socket_(io_, ba::ip::udp::v4()),
  endpoint_server_(ba::ip::address::from_string("127.0.0.1"), port_number_),
  n_receive_size_(4),
  receive_buffer_(n_receive_size_, 0)
{
  socket_.set_option(boost::asio::socket_base::reuse_address(true));
  socket_.bind(ba::ip::udp::endpoint(ba::ip::udp::v4(), port_number_));
}

void UDPClient::HandleReceive(const boost::system::error_code &error,
                              size_t bytes_transferred) {
// {do stuff .. }

  socket_.async_receive_from(ba::buffer(receive_buffer_), endpoint_server_,
                             boost::bind(&UDPClient::HandleReceive, this,
                             ba::placeholders::error,
                             ba::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
}

void UDPClient::ToogleCarUpdate(bool is_active, CarPtr car_ptr) {
  if (is_active && !thread_) {
      // {do stuff ..}
    socket_.async_receive_from(ba::buffer(receive_buffer_), endpoint_server_,
                               boost::bind(&UDPClient::HandleReceive, this,
                               ba::placeholders::error,
                               ba::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    // start io_.run() in new thread
    thread_.reset(new boost::thread(
        boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io_)));
    std::cout << "UDPClient: Started listening .. " << std::endl;
  } else if (!is_active && thread_) {
    io_.stop(); // stop service
    thread_->join(); // stop thread
    io_.reset(); // make ready for new run invocation
    thread_.reset(); // delete thread pointee
    std::cout << "UDPClient: Stopped listening .. " << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Now, everything works fine as long as UDPServer (running in a different process/application on the same machine) is instantiated before UDPClient.
More specifically, UDPClient's socket_.bind(..) must be called before UDPServer starts sending messages.

Interestingly, using

> echo "test" > /dev/udp/127.0.0.1/1122

always invokes the UDPClient's HandleReceive(..). That hints towards the sending routine being the issue. Does anyone have a suggestion on how to tackle the problem?

Thanks for your time,

Felix

Comment: `as long as UDPServer is instantiated before UDPClient` If you throw apples towards a non-existing basket, where do they go ?

Comment: But why does it work if I start the client first, and then use "echo" to send data, but not if I use the server to do the same? I feel I got something fundamentally wrong.